# Nginx configuration get proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am having some problems with nginx configuration. Here it is my configuration

```
    location /brandadmin/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:12001;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;

    }
```

The behavior is bizarre when I call a POST there is no problem but when i try to do a GET like http://localhost/brandadmin/customer/v0/customers?lastName=B passing and Authorization Header the downstream does not revives the call, it revives it only after I stop the call is stopped

If I bypass the NGINX i get not problem to perform the get request. Any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the problem maybe It is usefull for other people the solution was as simple as it gets

```
    location /brandadmin {
        proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:12001;
    }
```

By setting Connection "keep-alive" it worked can anyone explain why?